# Listing Permutations of Two Elements

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Let $S_{k}^{(n)}$ be the set of all possible lists of length $n$ containing exactly $k$-times $\sigma$ and $(n-k)$-times $\Delta$.
For instance, $S_{2}^{(4)}=\bigl\{\{\sigma,\sigma,\Delta,\Delta\},\{\sigma,\Delta,\sigma,\Delta\},\{\sigma,\Delta,\Delta,\sigma\},\{\Delta,\sigma,\sigma,\Delta\},\{\Delta,\sigma,\Delta,\sigma\},\{\Delta,\Delta,\sigma,\sigma\}\bigr\}.$

Clearly, number of elements in $S_{k}^{(n)}$ is $\binom{n}{k}$.

How can I have this list with **Mathematica**?

Answer (score 1):

```
With[{n = 4, k = 2},
  Permutations@Join[ConstantArray[σ, k], ConstantArray[Δ, n - k]]]
```

> {{σ, σ, Δ, Δ}, {σ, Δ, σ, Δ}, {σ, Δ, Δ, σ}, {Δ, σ, σ, Δ}, {Δ, σ, Δ, σ}, {Δ, Δ, σ, σ}}

Comment: I just solved myself using  `Flatten[Table[Permutations[Join[Table[\[Sigma],{i,1,k}],Table[\[CapitalDelta],{i,k+1,4}]]],{k,0,4}],1]` which is the same of yours.

Comment: If you want all tuples (which seems to be what you want) you can simply do `Tuples[{σ, Δ}, 4]` which gives `{{σ,σ,σ,σ},{σ,σ,σ,Δ},{σ,σ,Δ,σ},{σ,σ,Δ,Δ},{σ,Δ,σ,σ},{σ,Δ,σ,Δ},{σ,Δ,Δ,σ},{σ,Δ,Δ,Δ},{Δ,σ,σ,σ},{Δ,σ,σ,Δ},{Δ,σ,Δ,σ},{Δ,σ,Δ,Δ},{Δ,Δ,σ,σ},{Δ,Δ,σ,Δ},{Δ,Δ,Δ,σ},{Δ,Δ,Δ,Δ}}`.